# ngx-datatable Error with summaryRow when scrollbarV is activate

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have a problem with my datatable.

When I want to display a summary row at the bottom of the database, I got this error:

```
ERROR Error: query at index 10 failed: Fenwick tree array not initialized.
    WrappedError wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js:34
    Error es.error.cause.js:28
    query swimlane-ngx-datatable.js:1783
    getBottomSummaryRowStyles swimlane-ngx-datatable.js:2236
    DataTableBodyComponent_datatable_scroller_3_datatable_summary_row_3_Template swimlane-ngx-datatable.js:74
    Angular 42
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9
    core.js:6210:12
```

But if I put the summary row at the top, everything work just fine.

Here's my datatable:

```
<ngx-datatable
    class="material striped m-2"
    [rows]="leaves.list"
    [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    rowHeight="50"
    [externalSorting]="true"
    [loadingIndicator]="loading"
    [externalPaging]="true"
    [count]="leaves.nb_leaves"
    [offset]="page.pageNumber"
    [limit]="page.size"
    (page)="setPage($event)"
    (sort)="onSort($event)"
    [scrollbarV]="true"
    [scrollbarH]="false"
    [virtualization]="false"
    [summaryRow]="true"
    [summaryHeight]="50"
    [summaryPosition]="'bottom'" //Works if = 'top'
    style="height: 550px"
  >

    /*Columns definitions...*/

  </ngx-datatable>
```

Do you have an idea of how can I solve this?
Thank you very much